# SonarQube JavaSquid Sensor error with underscore numbering

Tags: java, sonarqube, squid, sonarqube-5.0

We are analyzing a java project, which uses JAVA 7 underscore numbering, but we are getting the next error. We assume it has to be with JavaSquid sensor. Is there a workaround or any update available to solve this?

```
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:100)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.executeTask(Main.java:70)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at org.sonar.runner.Main.main(Main.java:53)
Caused by: org.sonar.squidbridge.api.AnalysisException: SonarQube is unable to analyze file : '/opt/ATLASSIAN/bamboo-home/xml-data/build-dir/78217217/ER-EADC-JOB1/erpsaas/src/test/java/co/com/psl/erpsaas/general/importacion/comprobantesContables/ComprobanteContableExcelTest.java'
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:102)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.scan(JavaAstScanner.java:75)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scanSources(JavaSquid.java:131)
        at org.sonar.java.JavaSquid.scan(JavaSquid.java:124)
        at org.sonar.plugins.java.JavaSquidSensor.analyse(JavaSquidSensor.java:86)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:79)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:70)
        at org.sonar.batch.phases.PhaseExecutor.execute(PhaseExecutor.java:122)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:222)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:235)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:230)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:223)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.scan(ScanTask.java:65)
        at org.sonar.batch.scan.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:52)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:128)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:93)
        at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:78)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:171)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:95)
        at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:67)
        at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:48)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100_000"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
        at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:582)
        at org.sonar.java.model.LiteralUtils.intLiteralValue(LiteralUtils.java:57)
        at org.sonar.java.model.LiteralUtils.intLiteralValue(LiteralUtils.java:41)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.eval(ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.java:106)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.isConditionFalseAtInitialization(ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.java:84)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.visitForStatement(ForLoopFalseConditionCheck.java:52)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.AbstractForLoopRule.visitNode(AbstractForLoopRule.java:53)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:89)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visitChildren(SubscriptionVisitor.java:115)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.visit(SubscriptionVisitor.java:91)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanTree(SubscriptionVisitor.java:72)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.visitors.SubscriptionVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionVisitor.java:65)
        at org.sonar.java.checks.SubscriptionBaseVisitor.scanFile(SubscriptionBaseVisitor.java:33)
        at org.sonar.java.model.VisitorsBridge.visitFile(VisitorsBridge.java:123)
        at org.sonar.java.ast.JavaAstScanner.simpleScan(JavaAstScanner.java:94)
        ... 38 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a defect on the org.sonar.java.model.LiteralUtils class. looking at the code, there is a fix for the long data type, but not for integers. Underscores can be used on most numeric types based on Oracle's documentation, but Sonarqube seems to be considering only long-s.

Thanks!
Mauricio L.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your feedback and providing the stack trace. As you highlighted, the underscored integers are currently not handled correctly within the class `LiteralUtils`, which is part of the `Java Plugin`.

I created the following ticket to handle the issue: [SONARJAVA-1200](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1200). Note that the fix will be available as soon as the ticket has been resolved and is part of a release. Feel free to provide a [Pull Request on Github](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-java) with the fix if you want to contribute to the project!

As a temporary workaround and as long as a new version of the java plugin is not available, you could disable the rule `S2252` (*Loop conditions should be true at least once*) which is currently triggering the error.

Note that other rules also use the `LiteralUtils.intLiteralValue()` method and may cause you trouble for the same reason. If encountering other related issues, try disabling following rules:

- `S888` - *Relational operators should be used in "for" loop termination conditions*
- `S2197` - *Modulus results should not be checked for direct equality*
- `S2251` - *A "for" loop update clause should move the counter in the right direction*
- `S2695` - *"PreparedStatement" and "ResultSet" methods should be called with valid indices*